# Angular js Finding rendered Components

Tags: angularjs

I have used react and angular before but this is my first time using angular js.

I have spotted that you can render in html components similar to react and angular.
For instance the code I am trying to upgrade

```
     <div ng-if="!userSubscription.compliance">
                                <user-premise-groups-selector premise-groups="premiseGroups"
                                                              select-or-deselect-premises="selectOrDeselectPremises(currentEvent, currentPremiseGroupId)"
                                                              select-or-deselect-all-premises="selectOrDeselectAllPremises(currentEvent)"
                                                              all-premise-groups-selected="allCompliancePremiseGroupsSelectedLocal()"
                                                              is-user-premise-group="isUserPremiseGroup(currentPremiseGroupId)">

                                </user-premise-groups-selector>
                            </div>
```

I am trying to access this component like you can in angular or react (looks as if the data is passed down similar to props in reactjs) but am unsure of how to do this. Do these components work similar to other front end libraries such as react and angular? And how do I jump into these so that I can change the outdated code.
Within components folder this component does not exist however.

Comment: These are called directives in angular

Answer (score 0):

These are called directives in angular as components are slightly diffrent